# Error while using DefinitelyTyped definition file

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I am using showdownjs, and TypeScript. There is a definition file for the library from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/showdown/showdown.d.ts);

The problem is that I think this library is wrong. The documentation calls for a converter to be instantiated like this;

```js
var converter = new showdown.Converter();
```

But doing so with the TypeScript definition yields an error message telling it doesn't exist - because the namespace in the `.d.ts` is `Showdown`, but the library exists on global literal `showdown`.

The definition exports a module named `showdown` at the bottom, but this doesn't seem to be picked up by my IDE.

So my question: is this how TypeScript is supposed to work, or is it a good idea for me to try fixing the definition and submit a pull request to DefinitelyTyped?

Here is an example of how I am using showdown;

```js
import 'angular';
import showdown from 'showdown';

export class MarkdownConfig {
    constructor($showdownProvider: any) {
        showdown.extension('notice', () => {
            return {
                type: 'lang',
                regex: /^(^\S+)\s+(>)\s+(.*)/gmi,
                replace: (text: string, css: string, method: string, message: string) => {
                    let converter = new showdown.converter();
                    return text.replace(/^(^\S+)\s+(>)\s+(.*)/gmi,
                             `<div class="notice notice-${css}">${message}</div>`);
                }
            };
        });
        $showdownProvider.loadExtension('notice');
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you importing `showdown` package in your code?

Comment: I posted a snippet up above. But I have tried other methods other than `import showdown from 'showdown';`. That specific method of importing is the _only_ one that I've discovered to work.

Comment: And of course, like magic, it won't exhibit the error the moment someone else asks to look at it...

Comment: There it goes. I'm being told that `Property 'Converter' does not exist on type 'typeof Showdown'". Basically, `Converter` is supposed to be called as a constructor, but it's declared as an interface. This doesn't seem to cooperate with Typescript.

Comment: If I try to use lowercase `converter`, as seen in the tests on `DefinitelyTyped`, I am told that `Showdown.converter` is not a constructor.

Comment: Try importing like this `import * as showdown from 'showdown';`. It should be better.

Comment: That does work to make code that runs, but the typescript definition is still wrong. It is very insistent that `Converter` is not something you can call `new` on. And the alternative, `converter`, doesn't work at runtime.

Comment: changing `Converter` from an interface to a class in the `.d.ts` file fixes the issue - which is why I'm thinking of submitting a pull request to the DT repository. I just want to make sure I'm right that it isn't formatted properly first.

Comment: There might be an error on the definition file then, because according to it, `converter` is "newable", and `Converter` is the actual result of this instantiation.

Comment: Exactly! The definition file seems written wrong. I'm going to try and fix it and submit a pull request!

Comment: Hope I'm doing this right! https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/9358

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the showdown.d.ts currently in [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd/showdown/showdown.d.ts) says, is target to version 0.3.1:

```js
// Type definitions for Showdown 0.3.1
```

I ran into the same problem today, and issued a Pull Request targeting showdown 1.4.1 [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/9508).

Before the PR been merged, you can install the type definition from this location:

```
github:tan9/DefinitelyTyped/showdown/showdown.d.ts#aaaafcf9ba0e3d0a769bad1bbd55fbd38fdfbf48
```

Then in your .ts files:

```js
import * as showdown from 'showdown';

// register global extension
showdown.extension('notice', () => {...})

// use converter option to specify extension
let converter = new showdown.Converter({extensions: ['notice']});

// or use useExtension
converter.useExtension('notice');
```

Comment: The PR has been merged, you can now install the definition from the  DefinitelyTyped repository.